# Parse command does not change dataframe size in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 300 sheets in one Excel file and each sheet has fixed number of columns that contains data but data containing row number is changing in each sheet. I am using Parse command from Pandas in a for loop to process the data but it keeps old dataframe size. Let me explain with an example to be more clear;

In first sheet I have lets say 10 columns and 300 rows and parse command works very well for first iteration. In second sheet, I have again 10 columns but 250 rows in that case but when I try to create dataframe, it creates a dataframe of 10 columns and 300 rows again and last 50 rows are NaN that breaks my other work in the code.

Do you have any recommendations to fix this?

I put the parse command in the for loop with thinking that it will create dataframe everytime according to size of data in each sheet but it still keeps datasize of previous iteration because it was larger. In next iteration, for example, if I will have 500 rows, it will create 500x10 sized dataframe I guess.

Comment: What is "the parse command"? You will need to show your code.

Comment: `sheetLength = range(250)
loop_counter = 1

for i in sheetLength:
    df = XL.parse(i+2)`

That is my code, sorry about that.

Comment: What is `XL.parse()`?

Comment: XL is my Excel file that I have been working on and parse is taking one specific sheet and turns it into a dataframe.

Comment: Right. You will need to show us the actual minimal code for us to be able to help.